# Как сделать ссылку на переключение вкладки jquery-ui tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/
Не силен в jquery, нужно добавить отдельную ссылку в теле вкладки на следующую вкладку, в backend не могу передать ссылку, т.к. выводится это циклом и ссылки динамические, подхватываются из бд. Наверняка как-то можно найти активный объект, найти его соседа, подхватить href и вставить его в href нужной ссылки. Вопрос в синтаксисе, помогите разобраться, ребят + событие поидее обрабатывать какое-то надо, клик по вкладке по идее...
Идея такая, читаешь лонгрид во вкладке, доходишь до самого конца, нажимаешь на ссылку "читать следующий текст" и ссылка перелистывает на следующую вкладку, желательно конечно еще и возврат к началу текста сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы хоть пробовали читать, что там написано в документации? самое первое свойство - [`active`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active)

```js
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();


$("a.next").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var activeIndex = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active");
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", activeIndex + 1);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="fragment-1">
    <p>First tab is active by default:</p>
    <pre><code>$( "#tabs" ).tabs(); </code></pre>    
  </div>
  <div id="fragment-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
  <div id="fragment-3">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="next">next</a>
```